# Initial Condition in Spaghetti Cracking

Tags: differential-equations, linear-systems

In this Paper [B. Audoly, S. Neukirch - Fragmentation of Rods by Cascading Cracks: Why Spaghetti Does Not Break in Half](http://www.lmm.jussieu.fr/spaghetti/audoly_neukirch_fragmentation.pdf) on Page 2 (bottom), the author argues that using an integral of motion, the initial condition $\dot{\kappa}(s,0)=0$ implies $u''(0)=0$. Can anybody help, how this is achieved? What I have tried is using $\xi=\frac{s}{\sqrt{\gamma t}}$ and $\kappa(s,t)=\kappa_0 u(\xi)$ and then $$0=\dot{\kappa}(s,0)=-\frac{\kappa_0 \gamma}{2s^2} \, \xi^3 \frac{{\rm d} u(\xi)}{{\rm d}\xi}\Bigg|_{\xi=\infty} \, . \tag{BC}$$

Now using a CAS I can find the solution for the Equation (3) from the paper

\begin{align}
u(\xi)&={c_1}+{c_2}\,{\rm FresnelC} \left( {\frac {\xi}{\sqrt{2\pi}}} \right)  \\ &+ {c_3}\,{\rm FresnelS} \left( {\frac {\xi}{\sqrt{2\pi}}} \right)\\ &+ {c_4}\,{\xi}^{2} \, {\mbox{$_2$F$_3$}\left({1\over2},1;\,{3\over4},{5\over4},{3\over2};\,-{\frac {{\xi}^{4}}{64}}\right)} \, .
\end{align}

It is easy to use two boundary conditions $u(0)=u'(0)=0$ and conclude $c_1=c_2=0$. The boundary condition $u(\infty)=1$ is used last. But when I use the top relation (BC) I can not show that any of the remaining functions, actually satisfies this condition, but obviously $u''(0)=0$ is only satisfied by ${\rm FresnelS}$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Here is a comparison of both functions normalized to 1.
[image: Hypergeom vs. FresnelS]
To me they are pretty similar, not to say almost equivalent; in fact none of them has a feature that would make it a candidate for exclusion (apart from the violation of the condition (BC)).